# IP address on virtual bridge?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I would like to configure a static IP address on the virtual machine. This interface should be connected to one of the host physical interfaces via a bridge.
If I have understood the documentation correct, the physical interface attached to the bridge has no IP address. Only the Interface in the VM has to be configured with an IP address and must be on the same subnet like the default router which is a physical router connected behind a layer 2 infrastructure.

All the configuration examples shows an IP address configured on a virtual bridge. Why?

Answer (score 0):

*If I'm interpreting your question wrong, just let me know and I will edit to suit*

---

It is important to keep the distinction between host and guest clear, so I will try and do this with a hypothetical. I have a host (let's call it **kvm1**) with one physical NIC (eth0). That host is running one guest (let's creatively call it **guest**) which has been configured with one NIC. From inside **guest**, this NIC appears as eth1 (for clarity). If you want eth1 to have a static IP, all you need to do is add the IP using the `/etc/network/interfaces` file on **guest**, for example.

Now for the host configuration on **kvm1**: I'm going to assume you're using `/etc/network/interfaces` to configure host networking and that you have created a `br0` interface and added eth0 to it (whether using brctl or virt-manager or virsh). Now, as long as the guest's VM configuration has its single NIC set up to be attached to br0, you should be good to go.

If you're using `virsh/virt-manager`, you can try running `brctl show` from a terminal to check. You should have a `vmnetX` interface showing up as a member of `br0`, and your guest is now directly bridged to the physical interface eth0. Now, connect eth0 to the nearest Ethernet switch in your LAN subnet, and **guest** should retain its static IP and be accessible from the rest of the network.

---

I'm hoping that made sense.